# Storing Bit Values in vector in r

Tags: r

I need to store binary data in a variable `z` in R.

Code:

```
> z<-0101
> z
[1] 101
```

Actual needed is `z = 0101`

How to make this work?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit/index.html ?